# How do I change directories to a networked drive over SSH?

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, windows-server-2019

I have a networked drive mapped on a Windows Server 2019 Standard VM, which I can `cd` to locally on the machine in `cmd`. However, if I try to `ssh` into the same box and `cd` to the network drive, I get the following error:

```
The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

When I check `net use` via `ssh`, there is no error for the specified drive:

```
$ net use Z:
Local name        Z:
Remote name       \\networkdrive\dir
Resource type     Disk
The command completed successfully.
```

The command I am using via `ssh` to `cd` to the drive is:

```
$ cd /d Z:
The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

Ran `net use` locally:

```
$ net use Z:
Local name        Z:
Remote name       \\networkdrive\dir
Resource type     Disk
Status            OK
# Opens           4
# Connections     1
The command completed successfully.
```

I noticed another really strange thing. There is a mismatch in drives when running `wmic logicaldisk get name` locally (locally as in RDP) vs over `ssh`:

LOCAL:

```
$ wmic logicaldisk get name
Name
C:
T:
Z:
```

SSH:

```
$ wmic logicaldisk get name
Name
C:
```

Comment: It probably isn't "Z." locally...

Comment: it is, added an edit with the locally ran command

Comment: @Robert what is the right way to access network drives over ssh then? I'm logging into the same user account via ssh as I am via rdp.

Comment: More details can be found here: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/139